# Angular 1 ng-model not working on second input field

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Please help me in this regard,

I have generated two input fields dynamically in AngularJS controller. I will take first input value into the second one and the second input field is readonly.

If the second input value is greater than 50, a division should be visible.

```html
<input type="number" ng-model="firstInput"><br/>
<!--Some code depend on input value -->
<input type="number" ng-value="firstInput" ng-model="secondInput" readonly><br/>
<div ng-if="secondInput>50">Hello</div>
```

Here, I must check the div `ng-if` with the second input model, not from the first input.

Comment: It must be read only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 <input type="number" ng-model="firstInput"><br/>
 <input type="number" ng-value="secondInput = firstInput" ng-model="secondInput" readonly><br/> 
 <div ng-if="secondInput > 50">Hello</div>
```

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<input type="number" ng-model="firstInput"><br/>
<!--Some code depend on input value -->
<input type="number" ng-value="secondInput = firstInput" ng-model="secondInput" readonly><br/>
<div ng-if="secondInput>50">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Naresh did u test my answer?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use two variables, you can assign the value of firstInput to secondInput use **`$watch`** like this in your controller,

```
   $scope.$watch('firstInput', function() {
           $scope.secondInput = $scope.firstInput;
   });
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.$watch('firstInput', function() {
       $scope.secondInput = $scope.firstInput;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<input type="number" ng-model="firstInput"><br/>
<!--Some code depend on input value -->
<input type="number"  ng-model="secondInput"    readonly><br/>
<div ng-if="secondInput>50">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Sajeetharan, it seems good. But, I am generating the input fields dynamically. At the time of generating the first input field, I can not get to know the dependent input fields on it. When generating the second input only I will get to know on which input it depends on. So, I think $watch won't work in this scenario. Because I have 5 more pairs of inputs like this which depend on each other. Is it possible to apply $watch on all dependent inputs?

Comment: why the answer is removed